# CREATE USER disconnects from Azure database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure, azure-sql-database

In a SQL Azure Database, I want to create a new schema, a new login and a new user:

```
CREATE SCHEMA a AUTHORIZATION dbo ;

CREATE LOGIN a WITH PASSWORD = 'secret';

CREATE USER a FOR LOGIN a WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = a;
```

`CREATE SCHEMA` and `CREATE LOGIN` work. However, executing `CREATE USER` always **immediatedly** leads to a **disconnect**! No user is created! What's wrong ?

**EDIT -- The error message is:**

> Msg 10054, Level 20, State 0, Line 0
>
> A transport-level error has
> occurred when sending the request to the server. (provider: TCP
> Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the
> remote host.)

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I still do not know the exact source of the problem, an upgrade to the latest versions solved everything:

- Upgraded SQL Azure from V11 to V12
- Installed the latest SQL Management Studio (V12 - I was still on V11)

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't your `CREATE USER` be like below; use keyword `FROM` instead of `FOR`

```
CREATE USER a FROM LOGIN a WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = a;
```

**EDIT:**
Make sure you are creating the `LOGIN` in `master` database.

In `Master` database create the login

```
CREATE LOGIN a WITH PASSWORD = 'secret';
```

Then move back to your own database and create the `user`

```
CREATE USER a FROM LOGIN a WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = a;
```

Comment: No, both `FOR` and `FROM` and allowed: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms173463.aspx
And it doesn't change anything. Same issue.

Comment: @Giosco, see edit in answer if that helps. moreover, it looks like network related issue; is the error occurring continuously (or) intermittent?

Comment: @Giosco, No, if you can create a `login` then you do have right to create `user` as well; but this error tells me that; it's not be the problem with posted SQL but I am not sure though.

Comment: @Giosco, check this thread http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/04/16/a-transport-level-error-has-occurred-when-sending-the-request-to-the-server-provider-tcp-provider-error-0-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

This error message doesnt seems to be login related,best bet would be to log a ticket with azure support,if you are able to repro the issue consistently